# ¿Alguien sabe si es correcto que exista una tabla con un solo registro en una tabla y que ese registro sea una llave primaria?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera saber si es correcto que exista en la base de datos, una tabla que contenga un solo registro. Y que ese registro a su vez sea una llave primaria. He analizado la lógica de mis relaciones y no se me ocurre otra cosas que sea utilizar la tabla de esta manera.

Comment: Podría ser de ayuda que compartas tu diseño para saber la razón por la cual tu tabla sería definida de esta forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La respuesta de si es correcto que esa tabla tenga un campo definido como llave primaria, es que si es correcto si necesitas tener relaciones con otras tablas, además definir como llave primaria nos ayuda a que nuestra tabla tenga un indice único, como beneficios consitencia y performance.

Que tenga un solo campo definido como llave primaria (primary key), con un solo registro, es correcto si así lo requiere tu diseño, yo me pregunto para que te serviría una tabla con un campo definido como llave primaría y solo tenga un registro.

Comment: Bueno es todo un lio, pero diseñé la tabla de manera tal que una tabla llamada medios contacto tenga como entidades fuertes a "e-mail" y "telefono" y pudiera almacenar la información para tablas como "persona", "empresa", etc., evitando así tener tablas como "correosPersona", "correosEmpresas", "telefonosPersona", "telefonosEmpresa". Pero ahí es donde necesitaba la tabla que me permitiera hacer esta unificación. Por ello la tabla que necesito.